# Titanium How to Play the Sound in Loud Speaker after Recording

Tags: iphone, titanium

I am using sound_record.js file from Appcelarator KitchenSink, But I am not getting how we can play the sound in Loud Speaker after Recording is Finished.

I have used following code,

```
if (Titanium.Media.audioPlaying) {
    Titanium.Media.audioSessionMode = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_MODE_AMBIENT;
}else{
    Titanium.Media.audioSessionMode = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_MODE_PLAY_AND_RECORD;
}
```

But I am not able to play the recorded file in Loud Speaker.

Comment: Does the player is playing a sound?

Comment: Yes player is playing the sound. But not in Loud Speaker Mode. I also tried sound_file.js from KichtenSink Where it is playing in Loud Speaker, But After Recording its not Playing in Loud  Speaker.

Comment: what do you mean by loud speaker mode?

Comment: I meant in AMBIENT mode. So that sound will be maximum. By default it will be in PLAY and Record. How i can set it while Playing.

Comment: for maximum volume just set,  player.volume = 1.0;